# Error: Failed building wheel for equi7grid - Need help resolving build issues for pip install BioPAL

Tags: python

## Description

I'm encountering an issue while trying to install the BioPAL package using the command pip install biopal. The installation process involves the equi7grid package, and I'm facing a build failure specifically on macOS.

Following the instructions from BioPAL's readme file, I cannot finish the installation. I am able to create an empty biopal environment and Install GDAL library, but when installing the package I get:

## Error Message:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: equi7grid
  Building wheel for equi7grid (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1564 lines of output]
.....
running install_scripts
      error: invalid command 'bdist_wininst'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for equi7grid
  Running setup.py clean for equi7grid
Failed to build equi7grid
ERROR: Could not build wheels for equi7grid, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

**Question:**

I would appreciate any guidance on resolving this issue. Has anyone else encountered a similar problem with the **`equi7grid`** package during the installation of BioPAL on macOS? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: what's your version of python?

Comment: Latest version is Python 3.9.18 and 3.11.5 from Anaconda